# Regular expression *this close*, but still missing one type of symbol

Tags: c#, regex, string

**Believe this problem has been solved...see below note in Edit 2 for details.**

This is a fairly simple regular expression problem (I thought) that I suspect someone a bit more seasoned in them could probably solve quite readily.

I have the following expression:

```
(?<token>((?<!(\.\d*))'[^']*'(?=[ ,])|(?<!(\.\d*|'))[-+]?\d*\.?\d+(?!(\.|'))))
```

Here is the following test string:

```
34, 12., 'test', 106, 53, 'noon' ,'lunch' ,0.5,6, 8, .87 ,'foo', 'bar', 1253 ,'baz'.3, 1.2.3, .3'foo', 124`, 12.
```

The objective of the regular expression is really simple - to parse a list of strings consisting of elements that are either strings enclosed in single quotes, or numbers. Neither type of string may be a prefix or suffix of the other. A comma or whitespace is a sufficient delimiter between tokens. More formally, one might say:

```
<token-string> :== <token-string>,<token> | <token>
<token>        :== <quoted-string> | <number>
<quoted-string>:== 'a-zA-Z0-9' 
<number>       :== (floating point number)
```

The string portion of the expression is easy, and it is working just fine. The numeric portion is 99% there, but is giving me one bit of trouble: An integer followed by a period (eg 12. in the test string) with no following numbers is not recognized, because the negative lookahead check to prevent a subsequent decimal point fails - all because the basic floating point expression makes the decimal optional, causing the expression to parse the "1" in "12.", but stop on the lookahead.

I'm not sure at this point how to fix this recognition problem without tearing up the expression and almost starting over, but that hardly seems necessary. I tend to aim toward a simpler solution if I can, hence I made the inference that someone could look at my expression and see where I'm going wrong. Thanks.

**Edit** From the output string above, 'baz'.3, 1.2.3, and .3'foo' should *not* be recognized. All integers, such as 34, 106, 53 etc should be and are recognized with the expression as it is.

**Edit 2** I believe I may have solved my problem. I added an additional \d (digit) to the negative lookahead suffix check on the numeric portion, and now the "12." element is resolving. I'm going to run a few more tests on this to see how other inputs go. The revised expression is now simply this:

```
(?<token>((?<!(\.\d*))'[^']*'(?=[ ,])|(?<!(\.\d*|'))[-+]?\d*\.?\d+(?!(\.\d|'))))
```

Comment: Does it have to be a regex that breaks a <token-string> into a sequence of <token>?

Comment: Could you provide a list of exactly which values out of your example you want to match?  For example, should "12." count as a number?

Comment: In order to cross-reference the regex with the input, what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: Maybe i miss something, but it seems like you want to simply split a string by space or coma.

Comment: Just looks like a straight split on comma's that are not in quotes.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria Not quite - a straight split on commas or spaces will capture those characters within a quoted string. CAustin - 12. should be a number. PeteBaughman - The "sorta" BNF was just for convenience to illustrate what I was trying to do. Tokens not of the right format should be ignored. 'baz'.3, 1.2.3, .3'foo' of my test string are properly ignored. Only the "1" of "12." is recognized in the string. All other elements are recognized as described/desired. Hope that answers everyone's questions!

Comment: The regex pattern looks overly complicated, but maybe I'm not understanding where exactly you're splitting things up. It's fairly simple to capture all the individual values and do whatever you want with them. If you haven't found a solution I'd be glad to show you a pattern with a lot less overhead.

Comment: Please do, @i'l'i! Would love to see a simpler expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Capture Collections, you should be able to get all the tokens in a single Match.

***revised***

```
 #  @"(?s)(?:(?:(?:^|,))\s*(?<token>(?:'(?:[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'|(?=[^eE]*\d)[+-]?\d*\.?\d*(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?))\s*(?:(?=,)|$)|.)+"

 (?s)                          # Dot-All
 (?:
      (?:                           # Consumed leading comma
           (?: ^ | , )
      )
      \s*                           # Trim leading wsp
      (?<token>                     # (1), Capture Collection 'token's                                                                                                                                                                                                               
           (?:
                '                             # Single quoted string data
                (?:
                     [^'\\]* 
                     (?: \\ . [^'\\]* )*
                )
                '
             |                              # OR
                                              # Numeric form ( with bonus exponent )
                (?= [^eE]* \d )               # Lookahead must be a digit (and before exponent)
                [+-]? \d* \.? \d*             # Consume correct numeric form 
                (?: [eE] [+-]? \d+ )?         # Consume correct exponent form
           )
      )
      \s*                           # Trim trailing wsp 
      (?:                           # lookahead trailing comma
           (?= , )
        |  $ 
      )
   |  
      .                             # This character does not conform to token spec, just consume it
 )+
```

C# test case

```
 string strAll = @"34, 12., 'test', 106, 53, 'noon' ,'lunch' ,0.5,6, 8, .87 ,'foo', 'bar', 1253 ,'baz'.3, 1.2.3, .3'foo', 124`, 12.";
 string Allpattern = @"(?s)(?:(?:(?:^|,))\s*(?<token>(?:'(?:[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'|(?=[^eE]*\d)[+-]?\d*\.?\d*(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?))\s*(?:(?=,)|$)|.)+";
 Match Allmatch = Regex.Match(strAll, Allpattern);
 if ( Allmatch.Success)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Tokens:");
     for (int ctr = 0; ctr < Allmatch.Groups["token"].Captures.Count; ctr++)
         Console.WriteLine( Allmatch.Groups["token"].Captures[ctr].Value );
 }
```

Output >>

```
 Tokens:
 34
 12.
 'test'
 106
 53
 'noon'
 'lunch'
 0.5
 6
 8
 .87
 'foo'
 'bar'
 1253
 12.
```

Comment: Thank you for this, sln! This looks very promising! Let me study this a bit and if it works out I will mark this as the answer. Must admit that expression will take a bit of deciphering on my part :) Thanks again.

Comment: Well, @sln, there is a bit of a hiccup here - 'baz'.3, 1.2.3 and .3'foo' should not be in the final output. That, unfortunately, breaks the rule of a number not being a prefix of a string, or vice-versa

Comment: @DavidW - Added a revised sol'n. No problem, didn't know you would not be mixing styles. This version just gets valid tokens. Added a bonus numeric format and trimmed whitespaces. Good luck with it!

Comment: Great stuff, @sln. Thank you for all the effort.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
(?:^|,| )('\w+'|\d*\.?\d+)(?:,| |$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/PiCH86ZUKVNGWIVb)

The value is in capture group 1.

It does not match a number that *ends* in a dot (like `12.`). Changing the final `\d+` to `\d*` would fix that, with the consequence that a single dot would also be considered a match.

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with marked groups in debuggex, nor with C# at all, but the regex itself seems good.

Comment: Thank you much for taking the time and trouble to offer a solution. However, I do need for the number that ends in a dot, eg 12., to be recognized.

Comment: As I mention, there is a way to capture it, although you risk capturing *only* a dot.

Comment: Then or it: `(?:^|,| )('\w+'|\d*\.?\d+|\d+\.?\d*)(?:,| |$)`